# Left Rotate Problem in Even/Odd Sum using Tracer SCO Debugger Assembly

Tags: assembly, rotation, x86-16, bit-shift, dosbox

I am stuck on the code below. I have the following code for Tracer and SCO Debugger. I am compiling it using Dosbox and I want to add left rotate to the code but I can't find where to I am trying to ad ROL AX, 1 but it is not working.

Let say numbers are

> even 2,3,5,7,11
>
> Odd 1,3,5,7,9
>
> Sum 3,6,10,14,20

I want to make it look like

> 3,5,7,11,2

so the sum will be

> 4,8,12,18,11

```
_EXIT = 1

.SECT .TEXT
start:
MOV BX, 0
MOV CX, 5

sum:
CMP BX, 5
JE done
NOP
MOVB AL,(BX)
ADD BX,odd
MOVB DL,(BX)
SUB BX,odd
ADDB AL,DL
ADD BX,result
MOV (BX),AX 
SUB BX,result
INC BX
LOOP sum

done:
MOV CX,5
MOV BX,result
print:
CMP BX,result + 5
JE exit
MOVB AL,(BX)
INC BX
LOOP print

exit:
PUSH _EXIT
SYS

.SECT .DATA
prime:
.BYTE 2,3,5,7,11
odd:
.BYTE 1,3,5,7,9
result:
.BYTE 0,0,0,0,0
.SECT .BSS
```

Answer (score 0):

**`rol ax, 1` works on bits in that register, not bytes in an array.**  What you're looking for is like C++ [`std::rotate(first, new_first, last)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate) to rotate array elements.

You can swap two adjacent bytes in memory with `rol word [mem], 8`, or even do a dword rotate by 8, 16, or 24 bits to re-arrange bytes in a 4-byte chunk, but that's all you can do with one rotate.

So for example you could do this:

```
        ;; starting with prime = .byte 2,3,5,7,11 
ror dword ptr [prime], 8             ; 3,5,7,2, 11   ; x86 is little-endian
ror word ptr  [prime+4], 8           ; 3,5,7, 11,2
```

That's GAS `.intel_syntax`; I don't recognize the syntax you're using.  It looks like a hybrid of AT&T and Intel with round parens for addressing modes, but it does seem to be destination on the left.

That's fairly inefficient compared to just loading all 5 bytes and storing them back where you want them.  Specifically, you'll get a store-forwarding stall when the word load part of the 2nd `ror` reads 1 byte that was just stored by the dword store part of the first `ror`.  (A memory-destination instruction decodes to load + ALU + store operations.  The first store will still be in the store buffer when the 2nd rotate's load executes.  Assuming a modern x86 CPU executing this code natively; but since you're in DOSBox it's actually getting emulated not executed).

The more straightforward way to do this would be:

```
    mov    eax, [prime+1]         ; dword load: 3,5,7,11
    mov    dl,  [prime]           ; byte load: 2
    mov    [prime], eax
    mov    [prime+4], cl          ; 3,5,7,11,2
```

This is easy to extend for larger array sizes.  If needed you can write a loop to copy elements toward the front while you have the original first element saved somewhere else (in a register).